# Strapi Error Not Logical: Getting 'An error occurred during account creation' instead of 'Username already taken' when a existing username is used

Tags: javascript, strapi

I am using Strapi within my Next.js website.

Within my Strapi I have a Collection-Type of User
and a User has a `username, email, password`

username should be unique
email should be unique

When I purposefully use a existing email in the system to register it does return an error of 'Email is already taken'

Then if I fill out the email with a unique email and have the password and confirm password filled up the but the username BLANK I get 'Username already taken'

However if I enter a username that is already taken and already in the Strapi system, and then a unique email and then have the password and confirm password filled in with the same value so that they match I do not get 'Username already taken' which I want....what I get instead is 'An error occurred during account creation'

What is the reason for this and how do I fix this?
I want the error to say Username already taken because that is the reason why the registration cannot proceed.  That way the person signing up can fix the problem instead of thinking it is the system the system that is not programmed properly....

- **Strapi Version**: 4.1.7
- **Operating System**: Mac OS Monterey
- **Database**:
- **Node Version**: v17.0.1
- **NPM Version**: 8.1.0

I am using the correct strapi endpoint to register:

```
import { API_URL } from '@/config/index'
import cookie from 'cookie'

export default async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        
        const { username, email, password } = req.body

        

        const strapiRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/auth/local/register`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })

        const data = await strapiRes.json()

        console.log('data', data)

        if (strapiRes.ok) {
            console.log('strapiRes.ok')
            // @todo - Set cookie

            //Set cookie
            res.setHeader(
                'Set-Cookie',
                cookie.serialize('token', data.jwt, {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // a week
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    path: '/',
                })
            )
            res.status(200).json({ user: data.user })
        } else {
            console.log('else of strapiRes.ok')

            console.log('errors', data.error.details)

            if (data.error.details.errors) {
                console.log('x', data.error.details.errors)

                var msgString = data.error.details.errors.map((x) => {
                    console.log('x', x)

                    return x.message
                })

                console.log('msgString', msgString)
                res.status(data.error.status).json({
                    message: msgString.toString(),
                })
            } else {
                res.status(data.error.status).json({
                    message: data.error.message,
                })
            }
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST'])
        res.status(405).json({ message: `Method ${req.method} not allowed` })
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to show the backend code of your registration process ...

Comment: done...pls see shared code...

Comment: I meant the code behind `${API_URL}/api/auth/local/register` because obviously that's the one causing the error ...

Comment: ok sorry ...how do I look for that in the strapi project???  Because I'm calling the default strapi endpoint so I did not code that part...

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Have you inspected the response? Does it give any additional details? Maybe something is wrong with the configuration? Because is quite unlikely that a framework like strapi would struggle with such a situation ...

Comment: Yes the response seems to be pretty standard:  data {
  data: null,
  error: {
    status: 400,
    name: 'ApplicationError',
    message: 'An error occurred during account creation',
    details: {}
  }
}